# Selecting some linearly independent columns of a particular matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis, signal-analysis

Let us consider the matrix $C=A_1+A_2$ where :

- $A_1=(a_{k,l})_{k,l=0}^{n-1}$ is the $n$ by $n$ matrix given by $a_{k,l}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}(\cos\frac{2kl\pi}{n})$
- $A_2$ is the the $n$ by $n$ block diagonal matrix in the form of  $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  2 & 0 \\
  0 & B
  \end{array}\right)$  where $B$ is the $X$-shaped matrix in $M_{n-1}(\mathbb{C})$ whose nonzero entries are all 1 (it means the  nonzero entries of $B$ are appeared only on diagonals and antidiagonals which are all 1).

> Q. Let $C_k$ be the $k$th  column of the matrix $C$. Let us consider $\mathcal{V}=\{C_k : k\equiv_41\}$. Is $\mathcal{V}$ a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, at least when $n=2^m$?

p.s To prove it, I considered the square submatrix $C_0$ of $C=(c_{kl})$ whose entries satisfy $k\equiv_41$ and $l\equiv_41$. If we could prove it is invertible, then the claim would be proved!